# Chrome User Agent not displaying script - CSS fix?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I installed a WP theme recently and am having trouble getting a Facebook conversion box to display when I visit my site through Chrome. This problem doesn't exist on Firefox.

The response I get on Chrome is no visible pop-up box, but upon inspecting the element, I do see the code for the box in my header.php with a line from the Chrome User Agent saying:

script {
    display: none;

Is there a CSS solution to override the User Agent and get the script to display? Again, I have no problems with the theme on Firefox. Here's a [link](http://MissSophisticate.com) to my site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `script {display:none}` bit simply means that the browser shouldn't attempt to display the text inside any script element, or, the source of the script itself. You MUST NOT (and this is "MUST NOT" in the W3C sense) change this behaviour. So, I presume the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: If you're referring to the black box in the bottom right corner of the page (appears after scrolling down), then it works in both Chrome v35 & FF v29

Comment: You may try clearing your cache to see if it appears for you.
Also, you have a couple of console errors. It'd be a good idea to get those fixed, not sure if they're related or not (didn't take too close of a look)

Comment: @EnigmaRM I've cleared the cache, cookies, plug in data, etc. and I'm still not getting it to show up for me in Chrome. I too have v35. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Looks like you still haven't fixed your console errors. Some of them are pretty basic (syntax errors, undefined variables, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the source of your problem. It's a browser extension.

Your conversion box appears on my personal laptop. However, it doesn't on my work laptop. That lead me to believe that it was a conflict with the script & a browser extension. So I opened your site in an incognito window. Voila! it worked. The next step was figuring out which extension was blocking it. For me, it is LastPass (my work requires the use of LastPass).

If you have LastPass enabled as an extension, disable it. Then test again.

It'd also be a **good** idea to get these console errors figured out:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; (index):476
carouFredSel: No element found for "#foo1". jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js?ver=3.8.3:4232
Uncaught ReferenceError: paginateVal is not defined cgview.js?ver=3.8.3:28
```

**Solutions**

Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do about people's individual extensions. If this is an absolutely critical feature for you, I'd look at finding a different implementation of it. One that does not conflict with common extensions (that's the easy option).

The other option (harder) is to look into the code of the plugin/script that you're using for the conversion box and identify the conflict.

Last option (hardest) is to look at LastPass extension source code and identify the bug that is preventing other scripts from running. I've had issues with LastPass interfering with javascript in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your help @EnigmaRM. I'm very much a beginner with all this coding stuff so I have no idea how to fix those console errors, that's why I haven't done it yet...eep! It must be an extension issue as you said because when I visit my page on my sister's laptop using Chrome, I don't have this problem. However, the thing that's bizarre to me is that I don't have any new or actually existing extensions enabled so I don't know why it's an issue on my browser, especially because it was never an issue with the previous theme. Anyways, thanks for your advice, I appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try it in incognito mode in your own browser? (shortcut is ctrl + shift + n in chrome).

Comment: Hey, it works in incognito mode on my computer! So what does this mean?

Comment: It means that you must have some extension blocking things.

Comment: Got to `chrome://extensions/` and see what is enabled. And then start disabling them until things work.